# Binarizing 3-channel images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

```
circle_folder = 'C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\CR\start\circle'; 
name_circle = dir(fullfile(circle_folder, '*.png')); 
total_circle = numel(name_circle); 
rez_circle = [25 25]; 
m_circle = zeros(25*25, 5);
for n_circle = 1:total_circle 
    full_circle = fullfile(circle_folder, name_circle(n_circle).name); 
    images_circle = imread(full_circle); 
    images_circle = imresize(images_circle, rez_circle); 
    store_circle = imbinarize(images_circle);
    store_circle = store_circle(:);
    m_circle(:, n_circle) = store_circle;
    figure(n_circle); 
    imshow(m_circle);
end
```

I'm trying to pull images from the folder in question, resize them to 25 by 25 pixels, then turn them into a binary matrix. The code works until the point i attempt to fit the images into said matrix. If I make the matrix bigger, so it becomes 1875-by-1, it works, however, I do need the matrix to be of this size.

Answer (score 2):

What happened is that you loaded an m-by-n-by-3 image, i.e. a 3 channel image. You used `imresize()` to resize each channel independently, ending up with a 25-by-25-by-3 image. `imbinarize()` finally works on each channel separately as well.

Instead, before resizing, call `rgb2gray(images_circle)` to change your 3 channel image to a 1 channel image. Then you can call `imresize()` and `imbinarize()`, resulting in your desired 25-by-25 binary image.